# How to take out some code from Terraform main file to individual files for API Gateway paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have my main.tf file with this code:

```
provider “aws” {
  region = var.region
}
/*
REST API
*/
resource “aws_api_gateway_rest_api” “my_api” {
  name = format(“mock-api-%s-%s”, var.environment, var.region)
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = [“REGIONAL”]
  }
  body = jsonencode({
    openapi = “3.0.1"
    info = {
      title   = “example”
      version = “1.0"
    }
    paths = {
      “/testapi” = {
        get = {
          responses = {
            “200" = {
              description = “200 response”
            }
          }
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
            httpMethod           = “GET”
            payloadFormatVersion = “1.0”
            type                 = “MOCK”
            passthroughBehavior  = “when_no_match”,
            requestTemplates = {
              “application/json” = “{\“statusCode\“: 200}”
            }
            responses = {
              default = {
                statusCode = 200
                responseTemplates = {
                  “application/json” = <<TEMPLATE
{
    “foo”: “bar”
}
TEMPLATE
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
            “/myusers” = {
        get = {
          responses = {
            “200" = {
              description = “200 response”
            }
          }
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
            httpMethod           = “GET”
            payloadFormatVersion = “1.0”
            type                 = “MOCK”
            passthroughBehavior  = “when_no_match”,
            requestTemplates = {
              “application/json” = “{\“statusCode\“: 200}”
            }
            responses = {
              default = {
                statusCode = 200
                responseTemplates = {
                  “application/json” = <<TEMPLATE
[
    {
        “firstName”: “TestUser1"
    },
    {
        “firstName”: “TestUser2”
    }
]
TEMPLATE
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

resource “aws_api_gateway_deployment” “my_api” {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.body))
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}


resource “aws_api_gateway_stage” “dev” {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.my_api.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id
  stage_name    = “mystage”
}
```

As I keep adding more paths, my file is getting too big. What I want is if I can put code related to */testapi* and */myusers* in two different files. It will be easy to maintain and modify. I can add more files in future for more APIs.

Any other better scalable/modular solutions is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way would be to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) for your content. So you would end up with something as below:

```
    body = templatefile("path/to/body.json", vars)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my content is not in JSON. --->>
get = {
          responses = {
            “200" = {
              description = “200 response”
            }
......

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma You are already using `jsonencode`, so the end result is json anyway. So I'm not sure what do you meany that its not json?

Comment: Yeah, but can I keep writing my code in the current format instead of converting it to JSON manually? (Also, I'm going to give it a try with changing everything  in JSON and putting in a file, the way you suggested).

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma You could make everything into template, and just end up with `body = templatefile("path/to/body.json", vars)`. My answer is exemplary only. There are many ways you could use `templatefile` in your case.

Comment: I tried creating a json file. I converted everything to json and after deploying it didn't work. I don't wanna use one file to have all the paths. I wanna create testapi file, myusers file and so on. Can I create a file and copy paste this code instead of converting it to json ?

Comment: I tested it by converting it to JSON. Something is messed up. API gets created in aws but without the response. it doesn't return any response. Just to avoid messing up the existing code I thought I can copy the same code and make it work.

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma Yes, you can use exactly the same code. I don't know what you did, as you haven't provided any new code or templates that you used.

Comment: The code after "testapi" = is not in the json format. As soon as I put that in json file, it yells at me due to syntax errors.

Comment: So, either I have to format it to remove = and replace those with : or I should use some other file extension.